# Is AWS default_tags not supported in root_block_device?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to use the `default_tag` available for the AWS Terraform provider.

Documentation:

- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#argument-reference
- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#default_tags-configuration-block

From the doc, it says:

> This functionality is supported in all resources that implement tags, with the exception of the aws_autoscaling_group resource.

So, for all resources I have it works very well, except for `aws_instance.root_block_device`.

For example, I have:

```
provider "aws" {
  [...]
  default_tags {
    tags = {
      Env = prod
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ami           = xxx
  instance_type = xxx
  
  root_block_device {
    volume_size           = xxx
    volume_type           = xxx
  }
}
```

The default tag `Env = prod` is correctly added to the instance itself, but not for the `root_block_device` block.

So I'm wondering if `default_tag` is supported for this? It's true that the documentation says *supported in all **resources*** but `root_block_device` is only an **argument** of this resource, so maybe this is the problem?

I'm just looking for a kind of confirmation because the documentation is not very clear on this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not supported yet. There are two issues are still open

- [provider default tags aren't applied to root block devices](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/19890)
- [Better interaction between provider default_tags and aws_instance volume_tags](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/19188)

but you can use this workaround solution:

```
data "aws_default_tags" "example" {}
aws_instance {
  volume_tags = merge(data.aws_default_tags.example.default_tags, var.extra_tags)
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. So yes, my intuition was right, not available :/ I already use the workaround, from before `default_tag` was available but I wanted to update my code with something cleaner. it's still not the right time, too bad.

Comment: It is `data.aws_default_tags.example.tags` instead of `data.aws_default_tags.example.default_tags`, see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/default_tags